# Deserialize a Json with a field being of 2 types and one type is recursive

Tags: c#, json, typescript, telerik, deserialization

Having a typescript part from which I get the json result, need to parse the result in c# to get the object for working with it, but because we have here:

1. multiple type field
2. recursion

it is getting hard to understand how the deserializer should look,
I know that i need to use the JsonConverter for multiple type field, but how to deal with recursion along multiple type field?

here is the typescript code that is making the json:

```js
export interface FilterDescriptor {

  field ? : string | Function;

  operator: string | Function;

  value ? : any;

  ignoreCase ? : boolean;
}

export interface CompositeFilterDescriptor {
  logic: 'or' | 'and';

  filters: Array < FilterDescriptor | CompositeFilterDescriptor > ;
}

export declare
const isCompositeFilterDescriptor: (source: FilterDescriptor | CompositeFilterDescriptor) => source is CompositeFilterDescriptor;
```

an example of json's:
with recursion

```
{
"logic": "and",
"filters": [
  {
    "field": "type.group",
    "logic": "and",
    "filters": [
      {
        "field": "type.group",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": 2
      },
      {
        "field": "type.group",
        "operator": "neq",
        "value": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

without recursion:

```
{
"logic": "and",
"filters": [
  {
    "field": "type.group",
    "operator": "eq",
    "value": 2
  }
]}
```

this json is produced by using Kendo Ui for Angular from Telerik "CompositeFilterDescriptor"

*thank you.*

Comment: Is value field `number`?

Comment: it can be a string also, even an array like "2,4,5"

Comment: Hm.. It's more complex.

Comment: sidequestion: it your recursive example, the max number of recursions or are there more?

Comment: theoretically it can be several levels deep, mine shows only 2 levels.

Comment: Is it matters of your backend to know about `FilterDescriptor` type? Can you use just `CompositeFilterDescriptor`?

Comment: yes it matters, because this filter is generated from a grid, recursion is used when a column can be filtered for example 2 different queries like not equal to 5 and/or greater than 7, this kind a query can't be defined used simply FilterDescriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that C# does not have an equivalent for the 'discriminated union' construct (at least, I think that's what it's called ;-))

The only constructs you have available for polymorphism are interfaces and inheritance.

In this case, you need two types (`FilterDescriptor` and `CompositeFilterDescriptor`), and you need polymorphism because `CompositeFilterDescriptor` has an array that can contain either of these. In C#, you would need an interface or base class to express that:

```
interface IFilterDescriptor { }

class FilterDescriptor : IFilterDescriptor
{
    // ... (fields of FilterDescriptor)
}

class CompositeFilterDescriptor : IFilterDescriptor
{
    public string @logic { get; set; }
    public IFilterDescriptor[] filters { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally, you can't use Json.NET default deserialization, because that requires type information for polymorphic deserialization. You can however create a custom converter where you can check on the presence of certain fields to decide how to deserialize an object:

```
public class FilterDescriptorConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(IFilterDescriptor).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject o = JObject.Load(reader);

        // if the 'logic' field is present, it's a CompositeFilter
        var item = o["logic"] != null 
            ? (IFilterDescriptor)new CompositeFilterDescriptor() 
            : (IFilterDescriptor)new FilterDescriptor();
        serializer.Populate(o.CreateReader(), item);
        return item;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IFilterDescriptor>(json, 
          new FilterDescriptorConverter());
```